# "Expected a list of items but got type \"dict\".",

Tags: reactjs, django, react-native

I have a list of users for whom I am trying to add to an event using the add_participants endpoint.

My Django Viewset:

```
class EventsCreationViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Event.objects.all()
    authentication_classes = (TokenAuthentication, )
    @action(detail=False, methods=['POST']) #detail means we want to accept details (a specific Movie), not just "/"  
    def add_participants(self, request, pk=None):
        serialized = EventCreationSerializer(data=request.data, many=True)
        if serialized.is_valid():
            serialized.save()
            return Response(serialized.data)
        else:
            return Response(serialized._errors)
```

My React method:

```
const CreateNewEvent = () => {
    #Create an entry for each user in list
    const eventParticipantPayload = eventParticipants.map((n) => JSON.stringify({ eventName: eventTitle, eventLocation: eventLocation, eventTime: date, eventParticipant: n, votingClosed: "False" }));
    console.log(JSON.stringify(eventParticipantPayload))
       fetch(`http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/eventsCreation/add_participants/`, {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
            Accept: 'application/json',
            'Authorization': `Token <some token>`,
            'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        },
        body: JSON.stringify({eventParticipantPayload})
    })
    .then(res => res.json())
    .then(jsonRes => console.log(jsonRes))
    .catch(error => console.log(error));
```

My request data from console.log

```
["{\"eventName\":\"Hjhjhjh\",\"eventLocation\":\"Gjhgjhgjhg\",\"eventTime\":\"2020-08-18T11:15:00.000Z\",\"eventParticipant\":2,\"votingClosed\":\"False\"}","{\"eventName\":\"Hjhjhjh\",\"eventLocation\":\"Gjhgjhgjhg\",\"eventTime\":\"2020-08-18T11:15:00.000Z\",\"eventParticipant\":1,\"votingClosed\":\"False\"}","{\"eventName\":\"Hjhjhjh\",\"eventLocation\":\"Gjhgjhgjhg\",\"eventTime\":\"2020-08-18T11:15:00.000Z\",\"eventParticipant\":3,\"votingClosed\":\"False\"}"]
```

That fails with
Object {
"non_field_errors": Array [
"Expected a list of items but got type "dict".",
],
}

But.. when posting the below from POSTMAN, I get a 200 and my entries are added

```
[
  {"eventName":"swimming","eventLocation":"Xsport","eventTime":"2020-08-20T11:15:00.000Z","eventParticipant":2,"votingClosed":"False"},
  {"eventName":"swimming","eventLocation":"Xsport","eventTime":"2020-08-20T11:15:00.000Z","eventParticipant":3,"votingClosed":"False"}
]
```

So I don't think the issue is with my Django backend, but with how I am forming the list in the front end.

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is caused by additional curly brackets in the `JSON.stringify` arguments, that creates an unnecessary object.
You should change this:

```
body: JSON.stringify({eventParticipantPayload})
```

to this:

```
body: JSON.stringify(eventParticipantPayload)
```

Comment: I tried that and got a new error:     "non_field_errors": Array [ "Invalid data. Expected a dictionary, but got str." which I believe comes down to how I was trying to generate my eventParticipantPayload array. Ultimately I settled on just rewriting how I populate array to use a for loop instead of a map